# dplyr: Difference between unique and distinct

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Seems the number of resulting rows is different when using distinct vs unique. The data set I am working with is huge. Hope the code is OK to understand.

```
dt2a <- select(dt, mutation.genome.position, 
  mutation.cds, primary.site, sample.name, mutation.id) %>%
  group_by(mutation.genome.position, mutation.cds, primary.site) %>% 
  mutate(occ = nrow(.)) %>%
  select(-sample.name) %>% distinct()
dim(dt2a)
[1] 2316382       5

## Using unique instead
dt2b <- select(dt, mutation.genome.position, mutation.cds, 
   primary.site, sample.name, mutation.id) %>%
  group_by(mutation.genome.position, mutation.cds, primary.site) %>%
  mutate(occ = nrow(.)) %>%
  select(-sample.name) %>% unique()
dim(dt2b)
[1] 2837982       5
```

This is the file I am working with:

sftp://sftp-cancer.sanger.ac.uk/files/grch38/cosmic/v72/CosmicMutantExport.tsv.gz

```
     dt = fread(fl)
```

Comment: It may take some work on your part, but a small reproducible example would be better.

Comment: With small datasets it was giving the same answer from both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a result of the `group_by` Consider this case

```
dt<-data.frame(g=rep(c("a","b"), each=3),
    v=c(2,2,5,2,7,7))

dt %>% group_by(g) %>% unique()
# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
# Groups: g
# 
#   g v
# 1 a 2
# 2 a 5
# 3 b 2
# 4 b 7

dt %>% group_by(g) %>% distinct()
# Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
# Groups: g
# 
#   g v
# 1 a 2
# 2 b 2

dt %>% group_by(g) %>% distinct(v)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
# Groups: g
# 
#   g v
# 1 a 2
# 2 a 5
# 3 b 2
# 4 b 7
```

When you use `distinct()` without indicating which variables to make distinct, it appears to use the grouping variable.

Comment: @MrFlick This is an [open dplyr issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1110)