# How to best combine unique and match in R?

Tags: r, performance

I found myself often writing code such as

```r
#' @param x input vector
#' @param ... passed to [slow_fun()]
fast_fun <- function(x, ...) {
  u <- unique(x)
  i <- match(x, u)
  v <- slow_fun(u, ...)
  v[i]
}
```

To accelerate a slow vectorized "pure" function where each input entry could theoretically be computed individually and where input is expected to contain many duplicates.

Now I wonder whether this is the best way to achieve such a speedup or is there some function (preferrably in base R or the tidyverse) which does something like `unique` and `match` at the same time?

---

#### Benchmarks so far

Thanks for the provided answers. I've written a small benchmark suite to compare the approaches:

```r
method <- list(
  brute = slow_fun,
  unique_match = function(x, ...) {
    u <- unique(x)
    i <- match(x, u)
    v <- slow_fun(u, ...)
    v[i]
  },
  unique_factor = function(x, ...) {
    if (is.character(x)) {
      x <- factor(x)
      i <- as.integer(x)
      u <- levels(x)
    } else {
      u <- unique(x)
      i <- as.integer(factor(x, levels = u))
    }
    v <- slow_fun(u, ...)
    v[i]
  },
  unique_match_df = function(x, ...) {
    u <- unique(x)
    i <- if (is.numeric(x)) {
      match(data.frame(t(round(x, 10))), data.frame(t(round(u, 10))))
    } else {
      match(data.frame(t(x)), data.frame(t(u)))
    }
    v <- slow_fun(u, ...)
    v[i]
  },
  rcpp_uniquify = function(x, ...) {
    iu <- uniquify(x)
    v <- slow_fun(iu[["u"]], ...)
    v[iu[["i"]]]
  }
)

exprs <- lapply(method, function(fun) substitute(fun(x), list(fun = fun)))

settings$bench <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(settings)), function(i) {
  cat("\rBenchmark ", i, " / ", nrow(settings), sep = "")
  x <- switch(
    settings$type[i],
    integer = sample.int(
      n = settings$n_distinct[i],
      size = settings$n_total[i],
      replace = TRUE
    ),
    double = sample(
      x = runif(n = settings$n_distinct[i]),
      size = settings$n_total[i],
      replace = TRUE
    ),
    character = sample(
      x = stringi::stri_rand_strings(
        n = settings$n_distinct[i],
        length = 20L
      ),
      size = settings$n_total[i],
      replace = TRUE
    )
  )
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    list = exprs
  )
})

library(tidyverse)
settings %>%
  mutate(
    bench = map(bench, summary)
  ) %>%
  unnest(bench) %>%
  group_by(n_distinct, n_total, type) %>%
  mutate(score = median / min(median)) %>%
  group_by(expr) %>%
  summarise(mean_score = mean(score)) %>%
  arrange(mean_score)
```

Currently, the rcpp-based approach is best in all tested settings on my machine but barely manages to exceed the unique-then-match method.
I suspect a greater advantage in performance the longer `x` becomes, because unique-then-match needs two passes over the data while `uniquify()` only needs one pass.

```
|expr            | mean_score|
|:---------------|----------:|
|rcpp_uniquify   |   1.018550|
|unique_match    |   1.027154|
|unique_factor   |   5.024102|
|unique_match_df |  36.613970|
|brute           |  45.106015|
```

Comment: `dplyr::distinct()` instead of `unique()` may partly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198738/difference-between-distinct-vs-unique

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have vector `x` in mind, not data.frame. `dplyr::distinct()` only implements `unique.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to beat `unique()` and `match()` using `Rcpp` to hand-code the algorithm in C++ using a `std::unordered_map` as core bookkeeping data structure.

Here is the source code, which can be used in R by writing it into a file and running `Rcpp::sourceCpp` on it.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <int T>
List uniquify_impl(Vector<T> x) {
  IntegerVector idxes(x.length());
  typedef typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<T>::type storage_t;
  std::unordered_map<storage_t, int> unique_map;
  int n_unique = 0;
  // 1. Pass through x once
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    storage_t curr = x[i];
    int idx = unique_map[curr];
    if (idx == 0) {
      unique_map[curr] = ++n_unique;
      idx = n_unique;
    }
    idxes[i] = idx;
  }
  // 2. Sort unique_map by its key
  Vector<T> uniques(unique_map.size());
  for (auto &pair : unique_map) {
    uniques[pair.second - 1] = pair.first;
  }
  
  return List::create(
    _["u"] = uniques,
    _["i"] = idxes
  );
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List uniquify(RObject x) {
  switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
  case INTSXP: {
    return uniquify_impl(as<IntegerVector>(x));
  }
  case REALSXP: {
    return uniquify_impl(as<NumericVector>(x));
  }
  case STRSXP: {
    return uniquify_impl(as<CharacterVector>(x));
  }
  default: {
    warning(
      "Invalid SEXPTYPE %d (%s).\n",
      TYPEOF(x), type2name(x)
    );
    return R_NilValue;
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `factor` + `as.integer` like below

```
as.integer(factor(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did a benchmark and added it to the question. Unfortunately, the factor() approach is around 4-5 times slower than match(). Note that for type character, the benchmark isn't quite fair, because we could use `x <- factor(x); i <- as.integer(x); u <- levels(x)` where `levels()` already comes pre-packaged with the (sorted) unique values.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for benchmarking. You are right, `factor(x)` might be slower a bit than ``match`

Answer (score 0):

I found a cool, and fast, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697122/in-r-match-function-for-rows-or-columns-of-matrix) recently,

`match(data.frame(t(x)), data.frame(t(y)))`

As always, beware when working with floats.  I recommend something like

`match(data.frame(t(round(x,10))), data.frame(t(round(y))))`

in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to be sure, do you suggest `y <- unique(x)` for this usecase?

Comment: @AlexR  Yes,  I think  that's correct.   `x <- match(.....)` then  `y <-unique(x)` will get rid of duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found myself doing this a lot, especially with `basename` and `dirname` which are very slow (extra on Windows) but which I often use on data frames from multiple files, so the file path is repeated a lot.

To this end, I created a tiny package `deduped` that implements exactly what you have above using `collapse::funique` and `fastmatch::fmatch` to speed things up.

```r
remotes::install_github("orgadish/deduped")
```

(CRAN submission in progress)

```r
library(deduped)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

# Pretend that this is a data frame built from reading two
# csvs, one for each value of am, e.g. with read_csv(..., id="file_path")
xl_mtcars_with_file_names <- mtcars |> 
  slice(rep(1:nrow(mtcars), 10000)) |> 
  mutate(
    file_path = paste0("mtcars_am_", am)
  )

base_deduped <- function(f) {
  function(x, ...) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    f(ux, ...)[match(x, ux)]
  }
}

bench::mark(
  base = xl_mtcars_with_file_names |> 
    mutate(file_name = basename(file_path)),
  base_deduped = xl_mtcars_with_file_names |> 
    mutate(file_name = base_deduped(basename)(file_path)),
  deduped = xl_mtcars_with_file_names |> 
    mutate(file_name = deduped(basename)(file_path))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 base          47.55ms  58.63ms      17.9    2.44MB      0  
#> 2 base_deduped  14.09ms  15.04ms      64.4   11.33MB     30.3
#> 3 deduped        5.96ms   6.67ms     147.    10.97MB     26.8

# This is on macOS; on Windows, basename is even slower and the speed up is even larger.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Note: I had also considered combining `unique` and `match(x, ux)` into a single pass in C, and had even made a PR into `vctrs` to do that (`vctrs` has `vec_group_id` which gets `match(x, ux)` and I could easily get the unique values by the same path). But I found that using a faster unique and a faster match and combining in R, was still much faster (as in the benchmark I show above).